# MVC 5 Edit Action Saving Input Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, file-upload

When I'm editing a "salesmember" and I'm trying to save the new file path / or old file path, based on user input, it should either overwrite the image, or it will use the previous image stored in the DB.

But, when I try to modify the entity state, before I save the changes in my SQL Server, I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occured in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'SalesMember' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I'm modifying the SalesMember with that primary key. Which, it saves the image locally, but it won't save the DB row.

My Edit Action -----

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="SalesMemberID,FirstName,LastName,PageName,CellPhone,Email,InactiveRedirectTo,CustomText,Photo,Active, Position")] SalesMember salesmember, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        SalesMember SalesPhoto = db.SalesMembers.Find(salesmember.SalesMemberID);

        salesmember.Photo = saveImage(file, salesmember, SalesPhoto);


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            salesmember.AddDate = SalesPhoto.AddDate;
            salesmember.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            salesmember.IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            salesmember.AddUser = "admin";
            salesmember.UpdateUser = "admin";

            db.Entry(salesmember).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(salesmember);
    }
```

SalesPhoto Save Function --

```
private string saveImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, SalesMember salesmember, SalesMember SalesPhoto = null)
    {
        string photo = "";
        string returnPhoto = "";

        //File blank
        if( file == null )
            //If File Path For that User Already In DB, return that File Path
            if(! String.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesPhoto.Photo))
                return "/Images/no-upload-icon.jpg"; 

        //If File ! empty, Save image uploaded

        photo = Server.MapPath("/Images/" + salesmember.PageName.ToString() + ".jpg");
        file.SaveAs(photo);
        returnPhoto = "/Images/" + salesmember.PageName.ToString() + ".jpg";

        return returnPhoto;
    }
```

I believe it has to do with the LINQ Query, as when I remove the LINQ Query & saveImage method and just save the photo with a test path(i.e., "/Images/foo.jpg"), it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two entities (same type) with same primary keys in memory in Entity Framework.  `salesmember` and `SalesPhoto` if you want to have `AddDate` in your form Edit, you can Include it as a `HiddenField` in form, Or

> my recommendation is to deal with ViewModels not EF models in views to
>   ignore these Issues

```
 [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="SalesMemberID,FirstName,LastName,PageName,CellPhone,Email,InactiveRedirectTo,CustomText,Photo,Active, Position")] SalesMember salesmember, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    SalesMember SalesPhoto = db.SalesMembers.AsNoTracking().Find(salesmember.SalesMemberID);

    salesmember.Photo = saveImage(file, salesmember, SalesPhoto);


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        salesmember.AddDate = SalesPhoto.AddDate;
        salesmember.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        salesmember.IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
        salesmember.AddUser = "admin";
        salesmember.UpdateUser = "admin";

        db.Entry(salesmember).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(salesmember);
}
```

Comment: If I'm binding values from my view to salesmember, when I call db.SalesMembers.Find, and assign the return salesmember to "salesmember", won't that overwrite all previously binded values in salesmember?

Comment: @DaveBoz Yes it will (I understand something wrong), Include everything you want in Form post as a HiddenFileds and you will save a hit to database or deal with ViewModels and you can try something else (notracking) but not 100% sure it will work or not

Comment: @DaveBoz can you try `AsNoTracking` and tell me how it work ??

Comment: I was just going to use the hidden form field option. But AsNoTracking?

Comment: @DaveBoz I update the Answer `db.SalesMembers.AsNoTracking() .. ` .. try it and tell me the result !!

Comment: Well, none of the objects in the expression contain as .AsNoTracking() method.

Comment: @DaveBoz add refrence `System.Data.Entity` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: The golden rule of using Entity Framework: never, *never*, __*never*__ save the same instance of an entity class that was posted. Always pull the entity fresh from the database, and map over the posted values onto to that instance, before finally saving that instance.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If you could submit that as an answer, I'd be happy to Accept it.